# Ubuntu SSH to Centos Server

Tags: ssh

To SSH to a Centos Server I have to use:

SSH -c aes256-ctr server.name.edu -l myid

How can I make the cipher the default for that server without specifying it on the command line?

Answer (score 5):

You can set it in your user's ssh config file (if it does not exist, just create it by `touch config`). Put following line in your user's ssh config file (~/.ssh/config) or in global ssh config file (/etc/ssh/ssh_config):

```
Cipher <cipher>
```

And then you should be able to use ssh just like this without specifying cipher:

```
ssh server.name.edu -l myid
```